# Make CRUD with auto generate drop-down with two relation tables in GII

Tags: php, yii2

Is there any functionality in `GII` that will make drop-down directly from relation table?

I am using two tables `CATEGORY` and `SUB_CATEGORY` in database.

Where `SUB_CATEGORY` table having `category_id` from `CATEGORY` with foreign key constrain.

My question is that there any functionality in GII that will directly take drop-down  of `CATEGORY` in `SUB_CATEGORY` (CRUD) create and edit page? or we need to customize GII?

Comment: You need to customize GII.

Comment: Why someone give down vote?

Comment: I don't know. Someone play in this way. NO answer and downvote. I vote Up for you

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge. I need to customize GII for this.

Comment: I have posted an asnwer for resume.

Comment: Thanks. I will review yii2-gient and yii-anhanced-gii. I upvote your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes for your need you must customize Gii. Gii in standard version (Yii2-gii2) not give this option. You must to develop your solution. But you can explore the Gii-extensions. like this [yii2-giant](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-giiant/) or this [yii2-enhanced-gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-enhanced-gii). these are mainly oriented for relation between table  but in some way intersting.  I hope this is useful for you.